How can I configure htaccess to process markdown files with my php script?
I'm sure I've done this before but can't find out how to do it now.
On my web server, how can I configure .htaccess file to pass any requests for markdown files through my php script for processing and display in browser (as html)?
the php script is in /home/user/public_html/src/md.php
i don't want to redirect to it, the markdown documents url should remain in the browser.
I don't think this matters but I'll typically be accessing these files from links on html pages or from apache indexes pages if that makes a difference at all.
What I've looked at so far
I can get raw markdown files to display by processing as php by:
<IfModule mime_module>
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php82___lsphp .md
</IfModule>

this answer here requires adding Alias directive to my apache config but I don't have access so it must be solvable from .htaccess files.
I use some custom markdown symbols so using an existing javascript converter won't work.

AddHandler would only make sense, if you wanted to send each file through the PHP parser on its own. But if the files don't contain any PHP code, that won't achieve anything. "i don't want to redirect to it" - you want to internally rewrite the requests to your PHP script, so that it can then read & process the MD file contents, right? So using mod_rewrite, something like RewriteRule \.md$ /src/md.php [L] (RewriteEngine On first, if you don't already have some URL rewriting in place.)

You can then read the originally requested URL from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  or you pass it as a parameter to your script, RewriteRule (.+\.md)$ /src/md.php?mdfile=$1 [L]

@CBroe so rewrite isn't redirect? helps me realize a few things, i'll try it thanks

Yes, that's the general terminology - a redirect is "external", the client gets a response with a 3xx status code and a Location header with a URL value, that the client is then supposed to make a new request for (and it updates the address bar when doing so.) A rewrite is only internal - you tell the server, to answer this request, please serve or execute file XY instead. So with an internal rewrite, the client doesn't "notice" anything, and the browser address bar will keep the originally requested URL.
